# Solve quadratic equation using only 3 variables and arithmetic

Tags: math, restricted-source, arithmetic, atomic-code-golf

Write function which solves equation of degree less than or equal to 2 (`ax^2 + bx + c = 0`).

## Input

Function should get 3 parameters - floating point numbers which are coefficients of this equation. Coefficients may be zero (that means function must able to solve `bx + c = 0` and `c = 0` too).
Coefficients are between `-1000` and `1000` with 3 significant decimal digits but maximum 3 digits after comma, for example, `999.` or `3.14` or `0.233` but not `1001` or `0.0123`.

## Rules

- You may use only `+ - * / % & | xor ~ && || ! < > >= <= == != << >>` operators
- No built-in functions (that means no square root or power or similar functions)
- No variables except 3 function parameters
- You can't use complicated expressions - only statements of the form `a = b @ c` or `a = @ b` are allowed (`@` - any allowed operator and `a, b, c` - any variables, may be same or constants)
- No loops, recursion, goto's, custom types
- Casts and type conversion between integral data types are allowed
- Using features of dynamic typing (changing floating point number to array/object/something else that is not number) is not allowed
- If's are allowed with one or none operators in condition (`if (a) {...} else {...}` or `if (a==b) {...} else {...}`). Note that `if` itself and its condition scores separately
- You may use `try{}catch{}`

## Output

- Output should be passed by reference to input variables, if your language doesn't have such feature, you anyway should put result to input variables and print their values
- In variable `a` - number of real roots - 0, 1, 2, 3 (value greater than 2 stands for infinitely many roots)
- In variables `b` and `c` - 1st and 2nd roots (if none or infinitely many roots than any values, if one root then `c` - any value)
- Note that 2 equal roots is not the same as 1 root
- Precision should be at least 3 significant decimal digits

## Score

- Score is `[number of operators]` + `[number of if's]`. Assignment operators have score 0.
- Answer with lowest score wins.
- In case of same score answer with greater precision wins. If precision is same then first answer wins.
- `if(a != 0)` and `if(a == 0)` has score 1 (instead of 2) because `if(a)` or `if(a)else{}` can be used, however not all languages support it.
- For each `catch{}` +2 to score
- Use of 1 temporary variable of numeric type is +20 to score.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16393/discussion-on-question-by-user2992539-solve-quadratic-equation-using-only-3-vari).

Comment: If I write an answer in Java, what is the score cost for catching exceptions?

Comment: "*Precision should be at least 3 significant decimal digits*": what does this mean when the exact value of the root is `0`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor `0.00`. In this case, let first digit before comma be significant.

Answer (score 6):

### Hybrid of iterative approaches; score: 62

I originally posted an answer which purely used Newton-Raphson; however, in the cases of large `b` and `c` this requires a lot of iterations. Consider only the most interesting quadratics: those which have two solutions. If we normalise them to the form `x^2 + bx + c = 0` then we can plot the number of iterations required for various approaches as a function of `b` and `c`. For example, we can modify the continued fraction route to get the direct approach:

```
c = -c;
a = b * 0.5;
while (loopCount-- > 0) { // This loop would be unrolled in the final solution
    a = a + b;
    a = c / a;
}
// Roots are a and -c/a
```

That gives a loop count diagram of

```
2236...................6322
2224n.................n4222
22236.................63222
22224n...............n42222
222236...............632222
222224m.............m422222
2222236.............6322222
2222224j...........j4222222
22222234P.........P43222222
22222223d.........d32222222
222222222t.......t222222222
2222222225Z.....Z5222222222
22222222219/////91222222222
/////////////./////////////
222222222*********222222222
222222222*********222222222
22222222***********22222222
22222223***********32222222
2222223*************3222222
2222224*************4222222
222223***************322222
222224***************422222
22223*****************32222
22224*****************42222
2223*******************3222
2224*******************4222
223*********************322
```

where `c` is negative in the first row and increases downwards, `b` increases from left to right, `*` means negative discriminant, `/` means only one root was within tolerance in 62 iterations, `.` means no root was within tolerance in 62 iterations, and numbers are in base-62 with digits `0-9a-zA-Z`. This is pretty decent for a certain range, but fails completely for another range.

[bmarks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30076/bmarks)' original implementation is similar to (but not the same; this is a reimplementation from the continued fraction):

```
a = b;
while (loopCount-- > 0) {
    a = c / a;
    a = b - a;
}
// Roots are -a, -c/a (which is better than a-b)
```

with loop count diagram

```
1117...................7111
1112n.................n2111
11117.................71111
11112n...............n21111
111117...............711111
111112m.............m211111
1111117.............7111111
1111112j...........j2111111
11111115Q.........Q51111111
11111111d.........d11111111
111111113u.......u311111111
1111111116/...../6111111111
1111111111a/////a1111111111
1111111111111.1111111111111
111111111*********111111111
111111111*********111111111
11111111***********11111111
11111112***********21111111
1111111*************1111111
1111112*************2111111
111111***************111111
111113***************311111
11111*****************11111
11113*****************31111
1111*******************1111
1113*******************3111
111*********************111
```

My naïve N-R was quite bad, but the really interesting thing to note about it is where the worst areas are:

```
njfdcccccccccccccccccccdfjn
njgcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcgjn
njgc9999999999999999999cgjn
njgc9777777777777777779cgjn
njgc9666666666666666669cgjn
njgc9544444444444444459cgjn
njgc9521111111111111259cgjn
njgc9534444444444444359cgjn
njgc9535555555555555359cgjn
njgc9536777777777776359cgjn
njgc9536888888888886359cgjn
njgc9536899999999986359cgjn
njgc95368aaaaaaaaa86359cgjn
njgc95368aaaaaaaaa86359cgjn
njgc95368*********86359cgjn
njgc95369*********96359cgjn
njgc9536***********6359cgjn
njgc9536***********6359cgjn
njgc953*************359cgjn
njgc954*************459cgjn
njgc95***************59cgjn
njgc94***************49cgjn
njgc9*****************9cgjn
njgc8*****************8cgjn
njgc*******************cgjn
njgb*******************bgjn
njf*********************fjn
```

So the thing to do is to hybridise. For the areas where it's good, I use the continued fraction; for the rest, I use N-R, but I've done some optimisation: I've experimentally found two cutoffs and three initial values which converge in 5 iterations to a worst-case mixed error `abs(value - correct_value) / (1 + abs(correct_value)` of 0.000052. (Thanks to [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) for the idea of doing a case split). The final loop count (mixing the two cases into one diagram) is:

```
111555555555555555555555111
111233333333333333333332111
111133333333333333333331111
111125555555555555555521111
111115555555555555555511111
111112333333333333333211111
111111333333333333333111111
111111255555555555552111111
111111144444444444441111111
111111112111111111111111111
111111113222222222211111111
111111111333333333111111111
111111111444444444111111111
111111111111111111111111111
111111111*********111111111
111111111*********111111111
11111111***********11111111
11111112***********21111111
1111111*************1111111
1111112*************2111111
111111***************111111
111113***************311111
11111*****************11111
11113*****************31111
1111*******************1111
1113*******************3111
111*********************111
```

and the code is

```
solve_quad(&float a, &float b, &float c) {
    float t; // 20 points
    if (a != 0) { // 21
        if (c == 0) {
            // x(x+b) = 0
            b = -b; // 22
            a = 2;
        }
        else {
            // Normalise so that we're solving x^2 + bx + c = 0 and have `a` free to use
            // Hereon, mentions of b and c in comments refer to these normalised values.
            b = b / a; // 22
            c = c / a; // 23

            // Three cases:
            //   b^2 < 4c: negative determinant, no solutions
            //   b^2 < -4c: use Newton-Raphson
            //   Otherwise: use the continued fraction method that bmarks was the first to post

            a = b / 2; // 24
            a = a * a; // 25
            if (a < c) { // 26
                a = 0;
            }
            else {
                t = a + c; // 27
                if (t < 0) { // 28
                    c = a - c; // 29, c holds the determinant

                    // Carefully optimised case split:
                    if (c < 0.05) // 30
                        a = 0.025;
                    else if (c < 250) // 31
                        a = 2;
                    else a = 193;

                    t = c / a; a = a + t; a = a / 2; // 34
                    t = c / a; a = a + t; a = a / 2; // 37
                    t = c / a; a = a + t; a = a / 2; // 40
                    t = c / a; a = a + t; a = a / 2; // 43
                    t = c / a; a = a + t; a = a / 2; // 46

                    // At this point a ~= sqrt(determinant)
                    t = b / 2; // 47
                    a = a + t; // 48
                    t = t * t; // 49
                    c = t - c; // 50
                    // At this point a ~= b/2 + sqrt(determinant) and c holds its original value
                }
                else {
                    a = b;

                    a = c / a; a = b - a; // 52
                    a = c / a; a = b - a; // 54
                    a = c / a; a = b - a; // 56

                    // At this point a ~= b/2 + sqrt(determinant)
                }

                b = -a; // 57
                c = c / b; // 58
                a = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // bx + c = 0
        if (b != 0) { // 59
            a = 1;
            c = -c; // 60
            b = c / b; // 61
        }
        else {
            // c = 0
            if (c != 0) a = 0; // 62
            else a = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you take care of negative or zero discriminants?

Comment: @user2992539, fixed.

Comment: Advice: in the beginning you can divide `b` by `-2` to avoid in future `b = -b`.

Comment: @user2992539 ummm... I think I asked you about coercing unary operators into binary operations and you said I needed to separate them.

Comment: @MartinBüttner `-b` is unary operator, however `-2` is constant, minus is not computed during runtime.

Comment: I think that Newton method is following `x' = (x + c/x) / 2`. You are using `x' = (x - c/x) / 2` don't know why.

Comment: Looks like my code had almost as many bugs as the question.

Comment: I changed my submission to 11 iterations, which I think is necessary (see the justification in my answer). Please let me know if I went wrong with that somewhere.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I agree. Irritating.

Answer (score 6):

### C, 60

I happen to use the same square root algorithm (Newton) as Peter. However, I think we need to use two different starting values in order to get away with even 8 iterations. The maximum value of `b²/4-c` (the normalised discriminant) is for `b = -c = 1000`. The minimum value is for `b = 0.001; c = 0` (in fact, there are smaller values but these would be beyond the significant digits of b and c). If we split the range of values at `20`, we can use `0.1` as the starting guess for the lower range and `100` as the starting guess for the upper range and always converge in 8 steps. If I could be bothered to keep searching I think I could get this down to 7, and with a few more subdivisions probably even below 6 while still saving operations (but I can't be bothered right now).

```
void qe(&float a, &float b, &float c)
{
    float t; // 20
    if (a)   // 21
    {
        b = b / a;  // 22
        c = c / a;  // 23
        b = b / -2; // 24
        t = b * b;  // 25
        c = t - c;  // 26
        if (c<0)    // 28
        {
            a = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (c<20)  // 30
                a = .1
            else
                a = 100

            t = c / a; // 31
            a = a + t; // 32
            a = a / 2; // 33

            t = c / a; // 34
            a = a + t;
            a = a / 2;

            t = c / a; // 37
            a = a + t;
            a = a / 2;

            t = c / a; // 40
            a = a + t;
            a = a / 2;

            t = c / a; // 43
            a = a + t;
            a = a / 2;

            t = c / a; // 46
            t = a + t;
            t = t / 2;

            t = c / a; // 49
            t = a + t;
            t = t / 2;

            t = c / a; // 52
            t = a + t;
            t = t / 2;

            a = 2;
            c = b + t; // 55
            b = b - t; // 56
        }           
    }
    else if (b) // 57
    {
        a = 1;
        b = b / c; // 58
        b = -b;    // 59
    }
    else if (c) // 60
    {
        a = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (c<0)` scores as 2 - if and operator.

Comment: @user2992539, ah, I'm scoring that incorrectly too.

Comment: Maybe it worth find better starting value instead of huge amount of iterations.

Comment: @user2992539 good point

Comment: @user2992539 okay you can get it down to 7

Comment: @user2992539 Actually no, because c could be arbitrarily small. Even if I used a different starting value for `|c| < 1`, there is no starting value that works decently for `0.01` and `1e-127`. Not even 11 iterations are enough for that.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Specified tighter bounds.

Comment: @user2992539 alright, I got it down to 8 iterations, and I think I could get it down a bit more, but I'll need to do that some other time.

Comment: How can you use variable `t`?

Answer (score 3):

### C# (46)

Used a different way of computing sqrt(x) (continued fractions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Generalized_continued_fraction)

It fails for b=0 due to large rounding errors. I'm not sure how to fix that, but I hope I can help fellow contestants with a new way of doing the square roots.

Edit: Thanks to @Peter Taylor for the suggestion on how to handle b=0.

Edit 2: Thanks to @steveverrill for pointing out that there are only >2 solutions if c is also 0, thus requiring an extra if check.

```
       public static void doStuff(ref double a, ref double b, ref double c)
    {
        if (a == 0) //1
        {
            if (b == 0) //2
            {
                if (c == 0){ //3
                   a = 3;
                }
                else {
                   a = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                b = -1 / b;//4
                b = c * b;//5
                a = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            b = b / a;//6
            c = c / a;//7
            if (b == 0) //8
            {
                b = 1 + 1E-7;// still just one constant; since 0.001/1000>1E-7, b can never equal this value normally
                c = c + 0.25; //9
            }
            a = 2 * c;//10
            a = a / b;//11
            a = b - a;//12
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//14
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//16
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//18
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//20
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//22
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//24
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//26
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//28
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//30
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//32
            a = c / a; a = b - a;//34
            a = 2 / a;//35
            a = c * a;//36
            a = b - a;//37
            if (b == 1 + 1E-7) //38
            {
                b = 0;
                c = c - 0.25;//39
            }
            if (a == 0) //40
            {
                b = -1.0 / 2 * b;//41
                c = b;
                a = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (a < 0) //42
                {
                    a = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    b = -1.0 / 2 * b;//43
                    a = a / 2;//44
                    c = b - a;//45
                    b = b + a;//46
                    a = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought no one will find this method) It was the only method in my mind that uses only 3 variables without temporary.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, for a=1, b = -c = 1000, I got 
a=2.0, b=0.9990019950139413, and c=-1000.9990019950139.
for a=1, b= 0.001; c = 0, I got a=2.0, b=0.0, and c=-0.001.
Since a just scales it, I don't think it matters too much here.
My real problem is when b=0 and a,c!=0.

Comment: When `b=0` you should use other algorithm, or modification of continued fraction, because now there is division by zero.

Comment: `b = -c / b` should technically be split into two steps.

Comment: @bmarks Ah you're right, the c = 0 case is rather uninteresting. I guess the actually interesting tests would be `a = 1000; b = -c = 0.001` and `a = 0.001; b = -c = 1000`.

Comment: @user2992539 C# can divide by 0 and not throw an error. I tried setting b to a really small nonzero number, but that didn't work too well either.

Comment: In the case `b=0` the best thing to do might be to say that `sqrt(0^2 - c) = sqrt(1^2 - c - 1^2)` and set `c = c + 1; b = 1`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe larger value will work better (not tested)?

Answer (score 2):

## C, 46 excluding handling a=0 cases, with "fast squareroot" (not "fast inverse squareroot")

**I hope I've scored what I've done so far correctly. I don't know how much more I'll do on this because:**

1. I'm not sure if casting's legal, or how to score it (the union used in another answer is more efficient, but I've not used them before.)
2. I'm a little unclear on the meaning of "2 equal roots are not the same as 1 root." I assume this means that a quadratic will always have either 0 o 2 real roots (which may or may not be equal) and a linear equation (a=0) will have 1 root. I would point out the only infinite case is a=b=c=0. If a=b=0 and c is nonzero, there are no roots.

**Anyway, my main reason for posting is that I wanted to show that it's possible to define a "fast squareroot"** (which is more suitable for the needs of this question than simply copying the famous "fast inverse squareroot" as per some other answers.) Instead of subtracting `i>>1` from a constant, we add `i>>1` to a constant.

The principle of the algorithm is as follows:
Assume a float is stored in an imaginary little computer as `2^AAA*1.BBBB` (the 2 and 1 are not stored. AAA is known as the exponent and BBBB as the fraction.)

Performing a rightshift on the number `2^100*1.0000`=16 gives `2^010*1.0000`=4 which is exactly the correct square root. Repeating the process gives `2^001*1.0000`=2. So far we have seen perfectly accurate results.

Now we have an odd power of 2. When we try to calculate the square root of the number 2 by rightshifting, the odd digit of the exponent underflows into the fraction and we get `2^000*1.100` which in decimal is 1.5, an error of approximately +6% on the correct value of sqrt(2)=1.414.

Moving to practical implemenations the 32-bit IEEE float (and the 64-bit, 128 bit etc.) has a bias on the exponent, so we have to add a constant to the raw shifted value. Careful choice of this constant enables the error to be limited to a range of approximately +/-3% which is a pretty good starting guess for The Newton-Raphson method. I found the constant by trial and error (there is room for some improvement, on my test cases it is more likely to give a positive error than a negative error.)

Three iterations of Newton-Raphson cleans it up very well (and may be more than necessary.)

```
void quad(float &a, float &b, float &c) {
  printf("a=%f b=%f c=%f",a,b,c);

  int i;                             //score 20
  
  c=c/a;                              // c/a
  b=b/a;
  b=b/-2;                             // -b/2a
  a=b*b;
  a=a-c;                              // (b/2a)^2-c/a), score 25

  if (a<0) a=0; else{                 // score 27
    
    i  = * ( int * ) &a;                       
    i  = i >>1;
    i  = i+0x1FB90000;        
    c  = * ( float * ) &i;            //sqrt( (-b/2a)^2-c/a ) score 31


    i  = * ( long * ) &a;             //don't lose the value (b/2a)^2-c/a
    a=a/c;
    c=c+a;
    a=c/2;
    c  = * ( float * ) &i;            //second iteration
    c=c/a;
    a=a+c;
    a=a/2;
    c  = * ( float * ) &i;            //third iteration  
    c=c/a;
    a=a+c;
    a=a/2;                            //score 43 after 3 iteratations

    c=b-a;                            //-b/2a in each
    b=b+a;             
    a=2;                              //score 46
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (<s>29 45</s> 44)

Note that each `return` can be removed, simply by using else branch.. it's just more readable. The same with `if(!sth)` can be simply changed using else and empty if branch....

**edit:** Now, with casts allowed, this answer should be correct.

```
void quadr(float &a, float &b, float &c) {  
    b = - b;                //1
    if(!(b && c)) {         //3
        if(!a) {            //4
            a = 3;          //
            return;
        }
        a = 1;              //
        return;
    }
    if(!a) {                //5
        a = 1;              //
        b = c / b;          //6
        return;
    }

    b = b / a;              //7
    c = c / a;              //8
    c = c * 4;              //9
    a = b * b;              //10
    a = a - c;              //11
    c = a / 2;              //12

    int t = *(int*)&a;      //32
    t = t >> 1;             //33
    t = 0x5f3759df - t;     //34
    a = *(float*)&t;        //

    c = c * a;              //35
    c = c * a;              //36
    c = 1.5f - c;           //37
    a = a * c;              //38

    a = 1 / a;              //39
    if(!a) {                //40
        a = 0;              //
        return;     
    }
    c = b - a;              //41
    b = b + a;              //42
    c = c / 2;              //43
    b = b / 2;              //44
    a = 2;                  //
}
```

I might have missed some case, feel free to prove me wrong :)

Comment: This way you are using 6 variables - 3 integers and 3 float. Change better to casts. Although cast are not allowed (as 6 vars) it will be more readable I think.

Comment: @user2992539 Casts are not allowed? I don't see that in the spec?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @user2992539: Well, I'm using 3 variables, I only treat them differently. One union still takes only 4 bytes in the memory, not 8...

Comment: @Jaa-c Maybe I misunderstood how union works. Never have used them. Let it be as it is.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Actually I can allow casts, however I thought it's unfair because many languages doesn't support them.

Comment: @user2992539 Casts are implicit in most scripting languages.

Comment: @core1024 I mean casts like used here which allows you to get not integer part of float but it's representation in memory. Don't know languages other than C/C++ that can do that.

Comment: I don't think this meets spec: the function is supposed to take three variables which are floating point numbers, not three variables of a type you created.

Comment: Changed now with one temporary int variable...

Comment: But you're still using reinterpreting casts.

Comment: You can get rid of temp variable making casts together with computations like `a = *(float*)&((*(int*)&a) >> 1);`. However, it's ugly.

Comment: @MartinBüttner This answer can't be accepted, however it shows other approach and is interesting.

Comment: @user2992539: U can't use reference of an rvalue..

Comment: @Jaa-c Oh, too bad. Someone should write this in assembly)

Comment: @user2992539: Well how about current version? No reinterpret cast, only one local variable...

Comment: @Jaa-c It's ok, since I haven't specified type of temp variable.

Comment: It's still using the `.` structure reference operator, which isn't in the whitelist of permitted operators.

Answer (score 1):

## C - <del>50</del> 48

I use the 32-bit float shortcut for getting a good initial seed for the square root. That allows me to get away with just a few iterations of Newton's method. I haven't found a set of coefficients yet that yield unacceptable results (outside the specified precision).

Also, I am not sure how the spec treats pointer operations. For all I know this is disallowed, but hey, I had fun!

```
void primitiveQuad(float *a, float *b, float *c) {
    if(0.0 == *a) { // 1
        if(0.0 != *b) { // 2
            *a = 1.0;
            *b = -1.0/(*b); // 3
            *b = (*b)*(*c); // 4
        }
        else if(*c) // 5
            *a = 0.0; 
        else
            *a = 3.0;
    }
    else {
        *b = (*b)/(*a); // 6
        *c = (*c)/(*a); // 7
        *c = 4.0*(*c); // 8
        *a = (*b)*(*b); // 9
        *a = (*a) - (*c); // 10
        *c = *a; // store discriminant here for later
        if(0.0 > *a) // 11
            *a = 0.0;
        else {
            int x = *((int*)(a)); // 31
            x = x - (0x800000); // 32
            x = x >> 1; // 33
            x = x + (0x20000000); // 34
            *a = *((float*)(&x));
            {
                // add precision here through iterations

                // iteration
                x = *((int*)(a));
                *a = (*c)/(*a); // 35
                *a = *a + *((float*)(&x)); // 36
                *a = 0.5*(*a); // 37

                // iteration
                x = *((int*)(a));
                *a = (*c)/(*a); // 38
                *a = *a + *((float*)(&x)); // 39
                *a = 0.5*(*a); // 40

                // iteration
                x = *((int*)(a));
                *a = (*c)/(*a); // 41
                *a = *a + *((float*)(&x)); // 42
                *a = 0.5*(*a); // 43

            }
            *b = 0.0 - *b; // 44
            *c = *b;
            *b = *b + *a; // 45
            *c = *c - *a; // 46
            *b = 0.5*(*b); // 47
            *c = 0.5*(*c); // 48
            *a = 2.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but doesn't the use of `x` break the three variables rule ?

Comment: Oh, I thought it was just a 20-point penalty?

Comment: You're right, sorry - I didn't see that in the scoring - have an up-vote. :-)

Comment: Indirection (`*`) and casts are both operators and neither is in the whitelist.

Comment: I still think that language constructs that don't do any arithmetic (cast, indirection, other language-specific stuff) should be allowed... Otherwise all the answers will be mostly the same... But that's not up to me...

Comment: Question a bit updated.